# How to return all hours between two time stamps

Tags: sql, time, teradata

I need to return all the hours between two time stamps.

I have start_time and end_time.
If start_time = 11:00 and end_time = 15:15,

I would want the results to be:

Hoursbetween:

1. 12:00
2. 13:00
3. 14:00

Query base would be:

Select Id, start_time, end_time
from table

Using Teradata

Comment: Assuming start_time, end_time are TIMESTAMP, you can use something like `select id, begin(pd) from mytable
expand on period(next(start_time), end_time) AS pd by anchor anchor_hour;` - the NEXT because PERIOD type includes starting bound (but not ending bound) and you appear not to want starting value if it's exactly on the hour

Comment: And if you really don't want 15:00 either, you can truncate a timestamp to whole hours with `ts_col - (minute(ts_col)*60+extract(second from ts_col))*interval '1' second`

Comment: Thanks for responding!!! I am using the below, but terradata returns an error that it is expecting something between the "," and the word expand.

select id, begin(pd)

from
(select 
id, call_dt, call_time, 
call_time + dur as end_time,  Paus_cd, 
expand on period(next(call_time), end_time) AS pd by anchor anchor_hour
paus_time * INTERVAL '00:00:01' HOUR TO SECOND as "dur"
from datasource
group by 1,2,3,5)

Any help to solve would be great.

Comment: Something like: `select id, begin(pd)
 from (
 select id, call_dt, call_time, call_time + dur as end_time, Paus_cd,
        paus_time * INTERVAL '00:00:01' HOUR TO SECOND as "dur"
        from datasource group by 1,2,3,5
 ) my_starting_data
expand on period(next(call_time), end_time) AS pd by anchor anchor_hour` You can add more columns from the subquery to the outer SELECT if desired.

Comment: If you need more help please either edit the question to provide more detail (example data, what you tried, what you get, what you wanted) or close this question and open a new one with the appropriate info.